# AngularJs very slow on IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, web

We faced a very huge performance degradation on IE browser while building a large scale web application using AngularJs!
The application works flawlessly smooth on Chrome and FireFox, but very very slow and unacceptable user experience on Internet Explorer 11 !

I've searched many posts and couldn't find a clue on how to identify the problem.
We have rolled back the latest IE patches, but the problem still persists.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is practically impossible to answer, Please provide some more details, can you compare two identical (small) processes and compare their runtime? did you profile anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! It was the Angular Material Design library causing all the slowness of the entire page.
Once I removed it, the performance went back as before (very close to Chrome and FireFox).

Thanks #TehAbstraCt for your tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Try dissolving ur app into components, remove a few modules, see with what it works good with what it doesn't, there are many things IE sucks at, for my angularjs app it was the css, start with that.

Comment: I tried this approach, the more components I remove, the faster it became, but still IE sucks in performance compared to other browsers!